# Superpowered SDK Audio Encoder

Tags: audio, autoencoder, superpowered

Does Superpowered SDK have capablity for Audio Encode or in any way we can do Audio Encoding using this SDK? as i see Decoder is present, but for Encoder i don't see any class present. help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Superpowered SDK doesn't offer any encoders. Except saving to WAV.